# Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation requires unnecessary "using System.Web.UI"

Tags: c#, .net, eventvalidation

I have a page with a bunch of text inputs, dropdowns, and buttons. All manipulation of the inputs is done server side. Javascript only adds event listeners which manipulate the contents of the text inputs.

When I remove the unnecessary (dimmed)

> using System.Web.UI

I get the annoying `"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation=\"true\"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation=\"true\" %> in a page.  ...`

When I put it back in the problem goes away.

[image]

Removing javascript and all processing in `Page_Load` does not make the problem go away.

How weird is that? What is going on here?

Comment: Can't reproduce for a simple setup (textboxes & submit button control) with `System.Web.UI` import line commented out. Can you provide further details including example page markup and code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by a line break in a `<asp:ListItem>Big long item
with a line break</asp:ListItem>`.

Presumably, when the item with the line break was selected, the returned HTML no longer matched the source (since line breaks are converted to a space character).